# Dataflow zombie jobs - stucked during job update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

During the job update pipelines are stucked, one of the job is in "Not started" and other job in "Updating" status more than 10 days.

Pipeline stop button is not visible. Dataflow does not allow me to submit another job with the same job name. What should I do to remove the jobs completely?

[image: Jobs]

[image: Job detail_1]

[image: Job detail_2]

Comment: it is best to raise a support case and have support look at the job.

Comment: we have basic support plan subscription. I am disappointed that we need to have a paid support plan subscription for this issue.

Comment: Please create an issue using https://issuetracker.google.com/ if you do not have gcp paid support  plan and they will remove zombie jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these kinds of zombie jobs, you will need to file a support ticket, so that GCP support can force the job update, or force the job to terminate.

Please let me know if you are having any problems filing a support ticket and getting this figured out.

---

If you don't have a Support Subscription, and you issue is a Zombie job stuck on update, you can also file a **private** issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491268

In the issue, mention your project and Job ID, so we can find the job easily.

But please do not file other support issues there, and use the normal support channels if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have any paid support plan subscriptions.